# Why use different type of Assert methods?

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

I'm a bit new to unit testing and I find myself always using the language-equivalent version of AssertTrue, instead of learning the many different type of other Assert statements that are available.

If they all boil down to a true or false, am I missing anything really important if I do `AssertTrue(a == b)` instead of `AssertEquals(a,b)`  Or does it just help provide a more clear debug message if the test fails?

Comment: *does it just help provide a more clear debug message if the test fails*: yes. It also makes the code more readable, and simpler to write in many cases. Don't know the details of phpunit, but it's clearer to me to see something like assertThat(someCollection).containsExactly("a", "b", "c") than to see 3 assertions testing that element 0 is "a", element 1 is "b" and element 2 is "c".

Comment: Yeah, makes sense.  Ok, thanks for the feedback; just wanted a sanity check.  If you post as an answer, I'll flag you.

Comment: I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does it just help provide a more clear debug message if the test fails

Yes, but that's quite an important feature. I prefer seeing *Expected 'foo' to be 'bar'* than *Expected false to be true*.

It also makes the code more readable, and simpler to write in many cases. I don't know the details of phpunit, but it's clearer to me to see something like

```
assertThat(someCollection).containsExactly("a", "b", "c")
```

than to see 3 assertions testing that element 0 is "a", element 1 is "b" and element 2 is "c".